# how do I pass the current object being worked on to a member function by value?

Tags: c++

```
class A{
private:
    int num{0};
public:
    void func1(A obj){
        std::cout<<obj.num;
    }
    void func2(){
        // func1(/*pass current obj by value here*/);
    }
};
```

how do I pass the current object being worked to func1 by value from within the same class?

Comment: If you mean passing the object that `this` points to, you get access to it like for any other pointer: You *dereference* it, as in `*this`.

Comment: A small design-question: Why is `func1` a normal (and not a `static`) member function? What is its purpose? What problem is it supposed to solve? And why does it take its argument by value rather than by (`const`) reference?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude overconfidently i chose to make a chess engine(just good enough to work) for my oop project and i need to pass the chessboard object by value through the minimax function so previous states wont be changed. there are other alternatives but this way is easier.

Comment: Well you can still pass by (const) reference, as then the object won't need to be copied each call.